# AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute 'get_shape'

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow2.0, spyder, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to load images into a model using datasets. However, I keep getting an error that my tensor slices don't have the get_shape() attribute. I have confirmed that they don't by trying to call it within my code. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using:
Spyder 4.1.5 on Anaconda |
Keras 2.3.1 |
Tensorflow 2.1.0

```
# load dataset
dataset = h5py.File('3dshapes.h5', 'r')
print(dataset.keys())
images = dataset['images']  # array shape [480000,64,64,3], uint8 in range(256)
labels = dataset['labels']  # array shape [480000,6], float64

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images[1:10], labels[1:10]))
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((images[10:20], labels[10:20])) 

print("train_dataset", train_dataset)
print("test_dataset", test_dataset)
```

> train_dataset <TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((64, 64, 3), (6,)), types:
> (tf.uint8, tf.float64)>
>
> test_dataset <TensorSliceDataset shapes: ((64, 64, 3), (6,)), types: (tf.uint8, tf.float64)>
>
> File "C:\Users\Administration
> User.conda\envs\Keras\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\layers\convolutional.py",
> line 192, in call
> call_input_shape = inputs.get_shape()
>
> AttributeError: 'TensorSliceDataset' object has no attribute
> 'get_shape'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to setup a new Python environment on Anaconda and install Tensorflow and Keras. My existing environment was already setup with these, but various other posts mentioned that doing this can help, and it did.